# I cannot navigate in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to navigate from RecipelistComponent to RecipedetailComponent but failed. Actually I want that when I click an item from Recipelist then Recipedetail opens. so I am trying to pass Id on the click of Recipelist Item

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipedetailComponent } from './recipe/recipedetail/recipedetail.component';
import { RecipelistComponent } from './recipe/recipelist/recipelist.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RecipelistComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':id', component: RecipedetailComponent }
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**recipelist.component.html**

```
<app-recipe
  *ngFor="let recipe of recipes"
  [recipe]="recipe"
  [id]="recipe.id"
></app-recipe>
```

**recipelist.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { AppState } from 'src/app/store/app.state';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';
import { FetchRecipes } from '../store/recipe.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipelist',
  templateUrl: './recipelist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipelist.component.css'],
})
export class RecipelistComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  sub: Subscription;
  recipes: Recipe[];
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.store.dispatch(FetchRecipes());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.store.select('recipes').subscribe((result) => {
      this.recipes = [...result];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**recipe.component.html**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { AppState } from 'src/app/store/app.state';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';
import { FetchRecipes } from '../store/recipe.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipelist',
  templateUrl: './recipelist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipelist.component.css'],
})
export class RecipelistComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  sub: Subscription;
  recipes: Recipe[];
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.store.dispatch(FetchRecipes());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.store.select('recipes').subscribe((result) => {
      this.recipes = [...result];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**recipe.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../store/app.state';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe',
  templateUrl: './recipe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe.component.css'],
})
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() recipe: Recipe;
  @Input() id: string;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

**recipedetail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipedetail',
  templateUrl: './recipedetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipedetail.component.css'],
})
export class RecipedetailComponent implements OnInit {

  id: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: add this: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` also to your recipe-list component.html

Comment: Bingo!!! it worked, but is there a way so that I could have only one <router-outlet></router-outlet> and that should be in my app.component.html?

Comment: With your current route config using `children`, no.

Comment: @robert could you please add your answer so that I can accept it and let it benefit other's also. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The way you configured routing with child routes expect a "place" where these children to be loaded.

To make it work add

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

to `recipelist.component.html` component

Docs about nested routes: https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes